# Opening a new form via a keyboard shortcut

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-c#-express-2010

I am making a Windows Forms application and from `form2` I want to be able to press <kbd>Alt+1</kbd> to open `form3`. How would I do this?

The only code I know to open a new form is:

```
var myForm = new Form3();
myForm.Show();
```

... But like I said, I need to know how to activate this with a key press instead of a button press.

Here is the code that I am working with for form2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myForm = new Form2();
            myForm.Show();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to subscribe to your form2 KeyDown event,then you need to check for the keys that where pressed:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)//here you can choose any key you want
            {
                Form3 f3 = new Form3();
                f3.ShowDialog();
            }


        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes this did help thank you bat do you know the key codes for enter when i Googled it the key codes are unrecognized by the compiler

Comment: If you haven't already, you should set your form's KeyPreview to true.